# The pronunciation of words which begins 'con' and 'com'

Tags: pronunciation, prefixes, vowels

I know there is no strict rule on pronunciation of words in English but here my question is about the words which begin with **'con' and 'com'**, more than asking general rule.

When I look at the words begin with **'con' and 'com'**, I see mostly two patterns : One of them is **schwa** **/ə/** sound and the other one is **/o/** or **/ɒ/** sound.But the second  pronunciation can be pronounced slightly differently depending on dialect.

An example word for the first pronunciation is the word ***computer*** whose pronunciation is represented  **[/kəmˈpjuː.tər/](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/computer)**  in Cambridge Online Dictionaries.

An example for the second type of pronunciation for "co" could be the word ***contrast*** whose pronunciation is represented  **[/ˈkɒn.trɑːst/](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/contrast)**   in Cambridge Online Dictionaries.

So my question is there any rule/pattern which can help us guess how to pronounce these words correctly?

I am not asking about the words like *cool, come* or *coke.* My question is about words like *contract, combination, continue, combat.*

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'll throw in _cool_, _cozy_ and _counter_ as hints that the simple combination _co_ is absolutely arbitrary and no base for any rule that can be useful. There is the pronunciation of the _c_, which is constant, and the vowel sound _o_ which may vary wildly. Especially the second one may be very interesting, but not in combination with a random consonant.

Comment: @oerkelens Erm, you're wrong about that one old bean. There is a very regular rule about the pronunciation of the con/com/cor/col prefix (it's the same prefix where the /n/ undergoes dealveolar assimilation according to the position of the following phoneme. If the word is stressed on the "con" prefix then the pronunctiation is with /kɒn/ otherwise it is /kn/! Not arbitrary in any way but completely regular and quite interesting! :-) Please retract your close-vote! UInless I'm missing something?

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. How did my answer in 2014 get onto your question you asked in 2015? Time machine ...

Comment: @Araucaria there is another question which was merger with mine..and its date Feb 13, 2014.this could be the reason

Comment: @Mrt Yes, I think so :-)

Comment: To confuse you even further, are you talking about the noun or the verb "contrast"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very reliable rule of thumb for British English and General American is this:

- If the syllable *con* is stressed it will take a full strong, vowel, and the first syllable will be: /kɒn/.
- If the syllable is not stressed we will find a schwa, /ə/, or no vowel at all in the first syllable: either /kn/ or /kən/.

However, we should bear in mind that some regional varieties of English will have a full vowel in the first syllable of many of these words regardless of stress. So in Yorkshire English, for example, many speakers will say /**kɒn**ˈstɪtʃʊənt/.

This morpheme 'con' occurs a lot in English. That last sound in 'con', /n/, is very unstable both because it is an alveolar sound and also because it is nasal. It tends to change according to the following consonant. We find this prefix with different final consonants in words like: **col**lect, **com**memorate, **cor**relate. These types of word also show the same variation in their first syllables depending on the stress:

- colleague: /**ˈkɒl**i:g/
- collection: /**kə**ˈlekʃn/
- compensate: /**'kɒm**pənseɪt/
- computer: /**km**'pju:tə/
- correlate: /ˈ**kɒr**əleɪt/
- corroborate: /**kə**'rɒbəreɪt/

Both words *collection* and *corroborate* could be said with no schwa at all, and just a syllabic consonant - but the transcription for this is tricky in terms of syllabification, so I have taken the easy route and used a schwa. Similarly, *computer* could equally be said with a schwa instead of a syllabic /m/.

[Transcription note: in line with the Original Poster's question I have used Southern Standard British English transcriptions].

Comment: +1 for being totally correct about Yorkshire English (though I have never heard it called that before!) using /kɑn/ almost exclusively.

Comment: There are also 3 exceptions for this rule where *com-* represents stressed /kʌm/ (in most accents of English): *comfort, company, compass.*

Comment: @suməlic Indeed. It's only a rule of thumb, but I've never been able to remember the exceptions. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

A useful guide is that  /o/ sound tends to occur when the syllable is stressed and the schwa /ə/ sound is usually when the syllable is unstressed.

For example,

**cóntrast** and **contrást**

**cóntrary** and **contráry**

**cómbat** and **combátant**

**cómbine harvester** and **combíne**

Answer (score 4):

According to SPE -- **The Sound Pattern of English** (which I think is right about this matter), when the primary stress is on the second syllable, a heavy first syllable gets a secondary stress, but a light first syllable remains stressless, except for Latinate prefixes (like "con-"), which remain stressless even though they are heavy.

By "heavy", I mean that a syllable has a tense vowel or ends in a consonant. (The SPE account does not make reference to syllables, but that's what it boils down to.)

So, e.g., "computer" has no stress on the first syllable, even though it's heavy ("com-" ends in a consonant) because "con-" is a Latinate prefix.  Compare "pentagonal", with secondary stress on "pen".  Or, also, "campaign", with secondary stress on "cam".

In the SPE analysis, whether primary stress will fall on the first syllable of a word, like your example "contrast" (noun), is a separate matter.

Comment: Just posted too.  Snap!

Comment: Thank you this answer is like a candle in the dark pronunciation tunnel :)