# Rule for the pronunciation of the letter O as /ʌ/ vs. /ɒ/

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, vowels

If the letter o in a word is pronounced as a monophthong, it will fall 
into two types:

1. pronounced as /ʌ/ as in *color* ("/kʌlə/")
2. pronounced as /ɒ/ as in *lock* ("/lɒk/")

What I would like to ask is that is there a rule to determine which word will fall into which type?

Comment: I don't know enough to attempt a proper answer, but my sneaking suspicion is "yes, there are a lot of rules, with a lot of exceptions, which in turn create further rules and exceptions, to the point that it would be less complex to simply look up and memorize the pronunciation of each word; individually,  in a dictionary as you encounter them or find a need for them". But it's certainly possible that I'm wrong and few simple rules really do cover a large proportion of cases.

Comment: There's /ɪ/ as in "women". There's /ō/ as in "broken". There have been major changes in the ways some words are pronounced. There have been many borrowings from other languages. I'm afraid you are looking at a situation with more exceptions than rules.

Comment: There's also "aw" (sorry, don't have the IPA) as in "off".  Only likely rule I can think of is that if it's a one-syllable word, it's probably /ɒ/ (unless it's followed by 2 f's).

Comment: Related: [The pronunciation of words which begins 'con' and 'com'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227247/the-pronunciation-of-words-which-begins-con-and-com), [What's the current scholarly opinion on the “minims” explanation for the spelling of “love”, “tongue,” etc?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338132/whats-the-current-scholarly-opinion-on-the-minims-explanation-for-the-)

Comment: @MetaEd In _broken_ it’s not a monophthong, so that can be left out; and in _women_ it’s just completely irregular, which I think we can also safely leave out.

Comment: @Hellion _Lock_ and _off_ have the same /ɒ/ sound to me. How do they differ to you?

Comment: Where is @GhotiAndChips when you need em?

Comment: @Janus: It's the lot-cloth split, the round low vowel equivalent of the trap-bath split. "Off" has the "thought" vowel for most Americans.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet for me, "lock" is /ɑː/ as in *father* while "off" is /ɔː/ as in *caught* (which I know may not be helpful examples, but they were right there on the [wikipedia page....](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The way I pronounce "broken" I think it's a monopthong. But I've definitely heard other ways of pronouncing it. The problem illustrated by "women" is exactly my point: the language is too irregular to be able to compose a simple rule for this.

Comment: @MetaEd The phoneme represented by the letter ⟨o⟩ in _broken_, often called ‘long o’, is usually transcribed /oʊ/ or /əʊ/ (the latter mostly for BrE). There are dialects where it’s pronounced as a monophthong (many Scottish dialects, for example), but it is a diphthong in most dialects. There are also dialects where the ⟨o⟩ in _broken_ and the ⟨ea⟩ in _break_ can be pronounced the same, but in transdialectal English phonology, they’re still considered separate phonemes.

Comment: The simplest "rule" (one which gives "authorities" conniptions but is really not much less accurate than really technical, unintelligible ones) is that you get a "long O" sound ("photo") in "open" syllables and a "short O" sound ("fond") in "closed" syllables.  An "open" syllable is one that ends with the vowel (not trailing consonant) or with a consonant followed the letter E.  A "closed" syllable ends with a consonant.  (There are, of course, many exceptions to this "rule", but the same can be said for any other "rule" about pronunciation.)

Comment: (But note that the O in "color" is not a pure "long" sound, but slightly, uh, "colored".  One of the many exceptions.)

Comment: Remember that a great many people pronounce the O it *core, coat, cone* as a monophthong /o/.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/599686/2085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any useful rule for when O is pronounced as /ʌ/.

There aren't that many words where O in a stressed syllable is pronounced as /ʌ/, so I think it's most practical to just memorize the pronunciation of each word with this spelling pattern using some method like flashcards. Masha Bell's "[Improving English spelling](http://improvingenglishspelling.blogspot.com/2010/07/irregular-short-u.html)" blog gives the following list of words:

> The main alternative spelling for short u is o
>
> > Among,  brother,  comfort,  company,  compass,  front,  Monday,  mongrel,  monk,  month,  mother,  nothing,  other,  smother,  son,  sponge,  ton,  won,  wonder,  worry
>
> Sometimes o accompanied by redundant letters
>
> > Above, come, does,  done,  dove, glove, love, monkey, none,  shove,  some, tongue,  blood, flood
>
> In 21 words, the irregular spelling of the short /u/ sound is 
>        
> not followed by a doubled consonant (as in  funny, runny)
>
> > Colour,  covenant,  cover,  covet,  covey,  dozen,  govern,  honey,  money,  onion,  oven,  shovel,  slovenly,  stomach,  thorough.
> >     Couple,  courage,  cousin,  double,   nourish,   trouble.
>
> Sometimes the  letter o is redundant  (country,  southern,  touch,  young)
>       
> or is accompanied by further irregularities (enough,  hiccough,  rough,   slough, tough, one,  once).

There may be some words not on this list, but I would guess that the total number of words where O = /ʌ/, excluding inflected and derived forms like *sponging* and *brotherhood,* would be under a hundred.

There are a few sub-patterns—e.g. *-other* and *-ove*—but there are words with these spellings that have other pronunciations (like *bother* and *grove*) so they can't be used to reliably indicate which words are pronounced with /ʌ/.

The sub-patterns might be used as "warning signs" to indicate which words might plausibly be pronounced with /ʌ/: e.g. if the O doesn't occur in one of the following contexts (*oth, on, om, mo, wo, ov, ough,* the digraph *ou*) it's quite unlikely that it is pronounced as /ʌ/, although not completely impossible (as far as I can tell, the words *color* and *dozen* don't follow any identifiable sub-patterns for the use of O as a spelling of /ʌ/).

Another piece of evidence that there is no obvious rule: even native speakers show variation or change over time for certain words. For example, *conduit* and *conjure* were once commonly pronounced with /ʌ/, but now usually have /ɒ/. The words *hover, hovel* and *grovel* currently show variation between /ʌ/ and /ɒ/ (I don't know the relative frequencies, or how they differ between dialects). The uncommon word *wont* can be pronounced with various vowels, among them /ʌ/. The exact etymology of *donkey* is unclear, but some scholars think that it comes from the word *dun,* and that the currently standard pronunciation with /ɒ/ is a spelling pronunciation.

Comment: Don’t forget *cousin*, cuz. :) Why? Just *because*. I’m not really pleased with calling O “redundant” in that source. They are presenting matters as though English spelling has something to do with its current pronunciation, which is nonsense.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't agree with all of Masha Bell's opinions about English spelling, but I find her blog a valuable resource for lists of words like this with particular sound-spelling correspondences. (There are other sources that have lists like this, but the blog is free and online.)