# What is the root ? It seems like it is all suffixes and prefixes?

Tags: grammar, etymology, grammaticality, morphology, roots

What is the root of the word:

> Conversation

I think it is "Converse" but I am not sure.

Thank you

Comment: What researches have you done? Have you tried to see what a dictionary says?

Comment: Ya, the dictionary shows that it as con + ver +sa + tion

Comment: But, I am not not sure if the con is the root of the ver ?

Comment: No, no, the +s or .s (dots) just shows how many syllables the word "conversation" has.

Comment: By the way, if you check [this site](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) out, and [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4210/how-to-count-syllables) is specifically related to your question. And you are right the root of *"conversation"* is *"converse"*.

Comment: I'm sorry mathlearner, but I have to downvote this question because of [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [that](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @mathlearner - the root term is “vers” from Latin “versare” meaning  “to turn”. “Con”, the prefix, means “together with”. http://membean.com/wrotds/vers-turned - See also http://www.english-for-students.com/vers.html

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you define the concept of "root". Are you talking about something that is supposed to be part of the synchronic morphophonological system of present-day English, or are you talking about the diachronic derivation of the word? Sometimes its hard to separate these two concepts, but in many theories of morphology, they are theoretically distinct.

I think almost any present-day English speaker would realize that the noun *conversation* is related to the verb *converse.* So we probably can say that either *converse* is the root, or the root is contained in *converse.*

From an etymological perspective, the "con" in this word is a prefix (the Latin prefix *con-* roughly meant "with"; it is related to the Latin preposition *cum* "with").

There are some arguments for analyzing *con-* as a prefix not only in Latin but also in the morphophonological system of present-day English, but this issue is somewhat debatable. It's not necessarily obvious to all English speakers that *con-* can be considered a prefix in the verb *converse.*

1. Even though *converse* seems like it cannot be divided into a prefix *con-* and a free morpheme *verse* (*verse* does exist as an independent word in English, but not as a verb with the correct semantics to serve as a base for the verb *converse*) we could consider *-verse* in this context to be a bound morpheme of present-day English: there is another verb ending in *-verse* that can be analyzed as starting with a prefix, *re-verse,* and there are a number of words in other categories that end in *-verse* such as the adjectives *di-verse, per-verse, in-verse, ad-verse.* The semantic relationship between these words is not really obvious to a speaker of present-day English, but you could argue that they are morphologically related nonetheless.
2. Many speakers reduce the vowel in the first syllable of the verb *converse,* pronouncing it something like [kənˈvɜrs]. But we generally don't hear vowel reduction like this in word-initial unstressed closed syllables that did not originally come from Latin prefixes: consider the typically unreduced pronunciations of the first syllables of words like *monsoon, pontoon, trombone, Montana, pontificate, monstrosity, spontaneous.* This special phonological behavior of words that start with a *com-* or *con-* derived from the Latin prefix is mentioned in Greg Lee's answer to the following question: [The pronunciation of words which begins 'con' and 'com'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227247/the-pronunciation-of-words-which-begins-con-and-com). So it seems *con-* may have a special status in the phonology of present-day English, which might be explained in terms of it being a prefix. But one argument against analyzing *con-* as a prefix in the synchronic morphology of present-day English is that it has almost no productivity (unlike, say, *re-*). The most recent word that I could find in the OED that was created by prefixing *con-* to something else is the obscure scientific term *conalbumin,* for which the first OED quotation is from 1900.

So the root could be considered to be *verse* (or *-vers-*) if you consider *con-* to be a prefix. Another term that I have seen that seems like it might  be applied to **vers** is "paleo-morpheme", which is defined by Marina Yaguello in *[Language Through the Looking Glass: Exploring Language and Linguistics](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BhS0Rbb8pnMC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=morpheme%20etymology%20loan-word&source=bl&ots=ny4-CkZlzO&sig=SJ8EmFaBc-zMGzzNETVzdSt2rKc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE0Q6AEwCWoVChMIuvqwotHkxwIVEy_bCh1qMgMz#v=onepage&q=morpheme%20etymology%20loan-word&f=false)* as a word-part "whose status and meaning are impenetrable for many speakers" (p. 39 of the edition adapated from the original French by Yaguello and Trevor A. Le V. Harris that was published in 1998). [Another resource I found online](https://studfiles.net/preview/5115649/page:5/) uses the term "pseudo-morpheme" or "quasi-morpheme" to refer to things like the *con-* and *-ceive* in *conceive.*

If you get even more abstract, you could consider **vers** to be an "allomorph" or even a derived form of the root morpheme **vert**, which was the more basic form in Latin (in Latin, when a root ending in **t** was followed by a suffix starting in **t**, the two **t**s were replaced with **ss** or **s**). However, I think it's quite questionable whether things like this **t**/**s** alternation in words taken from Latin really constitute part of the synchronic morphophonological system of present-day English.